# Как обратиться к заранее неизвестному сложно вложенному свойству объекта?

Tags: javascript, json, парсер

Для парсинга XML необходимо создать объект со структурой сложной вложенности.

Есть объект:

```
object = {example: {path: "initValue"}};
```

Есть заранее неизвестный массив:

```
array = ['example', 'path'];
```

Необходимо переписать значение так `object.example.path = "value"`. Так как путь к свойству заранее неизвестен, для обращения к нему придется использовать массив `array`.

Первое что приходит в голову это слить все элементы массива разделив их точкой, чтобы затем обратиться через квадратные скобки. Результат будет идентичен такое записи:

```
object["example.path"] = "value";
```

Такое обращение создает одно свойство с точкой в имени, вместо одного свойства с вложенным вторым. Итоговая структура выглядит так:

```
object = {example.path: "value"}; // Полученная структура
object = {example: { path: "value"}}; // Ожидаемая структура
```

Решить пытаюсь на чистом JS (без jQuery).

Comment: Не совсем понятно, в чем проблема?

Comment: Для общего развития (близкая тема): http://habrahabr.ru/post/230649/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если правильно понимаю, у нас такой массив,

```
["example", "path"]
```

и такой объект,

```
var obj = { example: { path: "value" } };
```

и хочется получить или изменить значение `object.example.path`. Можно делать так:

```js
function getProperty(obj, path) {
  for(var i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
    obj = obj[path[i]];
    if(!obj) break;
  }
  return obj;
}

function setProperty(obj, path, value) {
  for(var i = 0; i < path.length - 1; i++) {
    obj = obj[path[i]];
    if(!obj) return;
  }
  obj[path[path.length - 1]] = value;
}

var obj = {
  example: {
    path: "value"
  }
};

setProperty(obj, ["example", "path"], "new value");
console.log(getProperty(obj, ["example", "path"]));
```

Comment: Ваш код делает то, что мне нужно. Но я не уловил такие моменты. Для чего условный выход из функции `setProperty` при отсутствии `obj`? Просто на случай если такого свойства в объекте нет? И второй вопрос. В функции `setProperty` переписывается `obj` спускаясь все ниже по дереву вложенности. То есть вместо всего дерева записывается только ветка. Почему при выходе из функции, объект сохраняет всё дерево, так будто в функцию был передан клон объекта. При этом переписанное значение сохраняется, так будто в функцию передали ссылку на объект?

Comment: Возможно для этого нужно создать ещё один вопрос?

Comment: @Aktash 1) Да, выходит если такого свойства нету. Можно удалить этот кусок кода если хотите, чтобы привести к ошибке если свойства нет. 2) Объекты сохраняются ссылками, а не значениями. Например, `var a = {}; var b = a; b.prop = "value";`, тогда `a.value === "value"`. 3) Не надо, ваши вопросы достаточно свазянные с ответом (и спасибо за это - иногда задают совсем не связанные вопросы в комментариях).

Comment: Спасибо за ответы! Про ссылки я знаю. Меня озадачило то, что `object` продолжает ссылаться на корневой объект, в то время как внутри функции ссылка `obj` "гуляет" по дереву свойств. Ожидал что `object` так же будет изменен. Не учёл, что при перезаписи `obj` объект на который он ссылается не будет изменен.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете написать

```
var path = array[0] + "." + array[1];

object[path] = "value";
```

Или, как тут подсказывают, можно написать

```
object[array.join( "." )] = "value";
```

Comment: Я бы предлагал `var path = array.join(".");`, так как количество элементов в `array` может быть не равно 2.

Comment: К сожалению оба способа не подходят. Результатом конкатенации строк будет строка. Я обновил вопрос и более подробно описал почему это не работает. Нужный результат можно получить таким кодом: `object[array[0]][array[1]] = "value"`.